# How to define a Parse Tree, and the equality of parse tree?

Tags: arithmetic, formal-languages, trees, context-free-grammar

I understand parse tree is used to describe a derive process of a context-free grammar $G=<V_N,V_T,P,S>$.

Thus in my point of view, it is a rooted tree $R=<V,E>$ with some kind of mapping of $f:V\to(V_N\cup V_T)$.

Furthermore, it also need to express the order of the produced string, so there must be an order relation $\prec$ on node of the tree $V$ .

Thus in my point of view, the parse tree need to be defined as $T=<V,E,f,\prec>$

But I would like to know how to precisely define each of the element within them. And furthermore, how to define the equality of 2 trees.

Because if the equality of tree is not formally defined, the ambiguity of a grammar cannot be defined.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That all seems fine to me. There are some precise formulations of [ordered rooted trees on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Ordered_tree). To that, you need to add your mapping $f$ of nodes to labels. The definitions in the linked article use a set of nodes and two relationships (the edges are implied by the vertical relationship). Two such trees are equal if there is an isomorphism between the two sets of nodes which preserves all three relation functions (vertical, horizontal, and label).

Comment: But grammar ambiguity is usually defined through reference to leftmost derivations. Every leftmost derivation using an unambiguous grammar produces a unique sentence.

Comment: @rici thanks a lot. but I would have further questions on definition of unambiguous grammar by derivation. It could be different derivation steps produce the same sentence. For example $S\to Acc|AB,A\to cc,B\to cc$, it is a meaningless grammar but obviously by leftmost derivation, it produce the same sentence.....

Comment: that's correct, and that means that the grammar is ambiguous. A grammar is ambiguous *precisely* if two sentences have the same leftmost derivation.

Comment: @rici thanks again, I may thinking that if there is another possibility that a left-most derivation is unique, but there would be non-left-most derivation that produce the same sentence with different steps??

Comment: If the grammar is non-linear then there will definitely be sentences with two or more different derivations. But only one of the derivations will be leftmost unless the grammar is ambiguous.

Comment: @rici thanks, I'm just wondering that "if two sentences have the same leftmost derivation", it is false for context-free grammar. And furthermore, there might be things like $S\to A|cc$ which one of the branch cannot produce a sentence..... So did you mean that "if a sentence can be produced by grammar, it has only one left-most derivation". and by "same left-most derivation", it means that the production used in each step and string derived in each step are all the same............

Comment: I don't understand your question in the first sentence. There might be productions which are not useful. That doesn't affect the definition of ambiguity. It's not possible for two different sentences to have the same derivation because a derivation ends with the derived sentence. What I said was that every leftmost derivation produces a unique sentence, which means that no sentence has two diferent left-most derivations. (Which is what you say at the end.)

Comment: @risi thank you. The first part is just saying that for context-free grammar, 2 different sentence must be produced by 2 different left-most derivation (different means production used and strings derived by each ordered step). If each $i$'th step use the same production on the same position of the current string. It would just produce the same sentence, even for ambiguous grammar............. But I understood what you mean and may I ask to post your answer so I can accept it....lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some precise formulations of ordered rooted trees on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Ordered_tree). The first formalism proposed in that article defines

> An *ordered tree* is a structure $(X, ≤_V, ≤_S)$ where $X$ is a non-empty set of nodes and $≤_V$ and $≤_S$ are relations on $X$ called *vertical*… order and *sibling* order, respectively.

For a parse tree, as you say, it is necessary to restrict $X$ to being a finite set, and to add a third relation $f: X\to (V_N \cup V_T)$ in order to label the nodes of a parse tree.

I've left out of the above definition a large number of restrictions on the relations which are required for the structure to be a well-formed parse tree. In addition to the restrictions provided in the linked Wikipedia article, there is a restriction of the labels in order that every node correspond to some production in the grammar. None of these restrictions is crucial to the definition of equality.

With that in place, we can say that two parse trees $(X, ≤_V, ≤_S, f)$ and $(X', ≤'_V, ≤'_S, f')$ are equivalent if there is an isomorphism between $X$ and $X'$ which preserves all of the relations.

But that's not the way that grammatical ambiguity is general defined. It is generally defined in terms of leftmost derivations.

Recall that a derivation of the sentence $\alpha \in V_T^*$ is an ordered sequence $\omega_0\to\omega_1\to\omega_2\to...\to\omega_n$ where each $\omega_i \in(V_N\cup V_T)^*, \omega_0 = S, \omega_n = \alpha$ and each $\omega_i$ is produced from $\omega_{i-1}$ by replacing some symbol $A$ in $V_N$ found in $\omega_{i-1}$ with the right-hand side of a production $A\to\nu\in P$. A derivation is a leftmost derivation if, at each step, the replaced non-terminal is the first non-terminal in the sentential form. (The point of this restriction is that every parse tree corresponds to precisely one leftmost derivation, although it might correspond to a number of different derivations.)

For completeness, two derivations are equal if they are equal symbol-for-symbol.

Then a grammar is unambiguous if there is no sentence which can be derived with two different leftmost derivations.